# When using Lambdas, is it more performant to pass by value through the capture clause or through passing as a parameter?

Tags: c++, lambda

This question just came to my mind, and I don't really know how to figure it out.

Let me show you what I mean:

```
int x = 1;

auto lambda1 = [x](){

 // do something with x, not specified here though
}

auto lambda2 = [](int x){

  // do something with x, not specified here though
}

lambda1();
lambda2(x);
```

Let's assume we would only have either lambda1 or lambda2 at a given time.

Which function would be faster in that case? I am pretty sure the difference is minimal, if there is even any difference at all, but this just caught my interest and I'd really like to know!

This might be very stupid to ask if we are only working with one int, but there might be a measurable difference in larger scaled lambdas.

Comment: I do not think it is about which version is faster. They are not the same. you can not do with the first one what you can do with the other.

Comment: You can't really compare the two, they do different things. Don't use one or the other for performance reasons, select depending on your needs.

Comment: [C++11 lambda implementation and memory model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12203426/4859885)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one translates to

```
struct _ {
    int x;
    _(int x_): x(x_) {}
    void operator()() const {...}
};
```

The second one translates to

```
struct _ {
    _() = default;
    void operator()(int x) const {...}
};
```

The former may have various effects* around the closure construction site, the latter may have the very same effects* around the closure call site.

* - depends

Comment: Interesting insight. Do you mind sharing the resource for this?

Comment: [how-are-c11-lambdas-represented-and-passed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921247/how-are-c11-lambdas-represented-and-passed)